# Is there a storyline revolving around Padme's pregnancy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, padme

Did a quick search and could only find fanfics. Is there a Legends or canon arc that delves into the difficulties Padme faced while she was pregnant? Or perhaps something unrelated that gives more insight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel)) indicates that she didn't face many problems at all. Like many slim women, she was able to conceal her pregnancy by simply wearing larger, non-figure-hugging clothes. Within her own apartments, where she can restrict who visits, she seems quite happy to wear clothes that show her bump.

> *And she watched that joy fade as he began to understand that their
> marriage could not stay hidden much longer; **that even the voluminous
> robes she wore could not conceal a pregnancy forever.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

She then died shortly afterwards and her pregnancy became public knowledge.

---

To the best of my knowledge, there are no stories (films, books, short-stories, comics, etc) that *specifically* deal with her pregnancy.

Comment: Disney's "What Padme Expected When She Was Expecting" isn't due out until 2025.